# How to make the logo zoom when hovering over

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on the left side of my nav bar and I want it to be able to like have a zoom effect when you hover the mouse over any ideas? I did try some codes on codeine but for some reason they don't work I think I need jquery but i don't want to use that for now. The `.logo` is the nav bar logo. Any help would be great!

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #D2691E;
}

.logo {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: -65px;
  left: -210px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.logo>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.logo>a:hover {}

.banner1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Trexon Music </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="default.asp">
        <img src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/Bannerlogo.psd">
      </a>
    </div>
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="music.asp">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="merc.asp">Merchandise</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="banner">
    <img class="banner1" src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/Cover.psd">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you want to upload a logo to your website, use the following file formats for web:

**gif**, **png**, **jpeg**

Open your **psd** file in psd editing tool like **photoshop** or **illustrator** and make it to one of the above mentioned format.

And if you want zoom effect on hover try the **CSS3** `transition` and `transform` property.

```
.logo img {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.logo:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use following CSS for this

```
.logo img {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.logo:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use .PNG or .JPG image.

Than apply hover effect on the logo image.

```
.logo img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.logo:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The concept can be cleared at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/afinedayproductions/pen/EzvLp)

Answer (score 0):

you should use png, jpg, jpeg, ... for image. Do not use .psd file

if you want zoom effect for image just add the below css

```
.logo img {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.logo:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I did what you said but it hover zooms before I even reach the logo, any suggestions to make it right?

Comment: I see. please change the css

`.logo img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`.logo a > img :hover{  height: 100px; width: 100px;}`